# Opções de Frequência Schedule Laravel não funcionam

Tags: laravel-5

Estou com problemas no Cron executando comandos no `Laravel 5.5`, executa o comando somente a cada minuto, não obedecendo as opções de frequência como a cada 5 minutos.

Exemplo:

```
$schedule->command('create:log')->everyFiveMinutes();
```

Meu cron esta assim:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/Test/artisan create:log >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Coloque toda a classe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***O*** [comando descrito na documentação é](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction):

```
* * * * * php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

***no seu caso***:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/Test/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

<sup>***Referencia:*** https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#introduction</sup>

Comment: Obrigado, problema resolvido !